# Task kworker/3:1:149 blocked for more than 120 seconds | Ubuntu 20.4 LTS

Tags: networking, 20.04, kernel, shutdown, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 and today my wired connection does not connect at all. It does not have to do with the cable or the connection itself, because it works with other PCs.

I tried to reboot and I got the following error :

```
[605.268765] INFO: task kworker/3:1:149 blocked for more than 120 seconds. <br/>  [605.268827] Tainted: P W OE 5.15.0-41-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu <br/>
[605.268878] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message. <br/> 
[605.269089] INFO: task ThreadPoolForeg:3270 blocked for more than 120 seconds. <br/>
[605.269139] Tainted: P W OE 5.15.0-41-generic #44 20.04.1-Ubuntu 1605.269188] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message. <br/>
```

My kernel is `5.15.0-41-generic` (last updated on 24/06/2022).

Is this issue related to wired connection one ? How can I resolve this ? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so apparently, by rolling back to the previous kernel `5.15.0-52-generic` everything works fine.

P.S. In order to boot with a previous kernel, people suggest holding `shift` while booting, in my case only `Esc` worked.